# URL just removes parameters

Tags: http

I've created an API for use on my website.

The API I made strips everything using mysql_real_escape_string then puts it into the database.

But the problem I'm having is the URL that my php scripts are using to access the API is cut short sometimes...

Which I have narrowed down to one of the parameters...

When its *Ford Mondeo 22'* the URL that is passed to simplexml_load_file is

---

http://mydomain.com/api/create.xml?api_number=brho15p6z1dhqwf5tsff&env=live&number=AJ20023232&title=Ford Mondeo 22'&image=http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/914955-150x150.jpg

---

but the API reports back the URL accessed as

---

http://mydomain.com/api/create.xml?api_number=brho15p6z1dhqwf5tsff&env=live&number=AJ20023232&title=Ford

---

If I remove the single quote then everything works fine, any idea how to correct this I suspect there's something I've overlooked when passing variables in the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the spaces in the "Ford Mondeo 22'" value that is causing the problem. You cannot have a spaces in the URL. You need to use escape characters. The encoded version of the parameter should be

Ford%20Mondeo%2022'

%20 is the escape character for space

I.e. the whole URL should read as follows:

```
http://mydomain.com/api/create.xml?api_number=brho15p6z1dhqwf5tsff&env=live&number=AJ20023232&title=Ford%20Mondeo%2022'&image=http://mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/914955-150x150.jpg
```

**EDIT:**
Your comment indicates that you use PHP. In PHP, you can use urlencode($foo) and urldecode($foo) to switch between the normal string and the encoding string.

Comment: Thanks is there a way to do this in PHP? Preferably to the entire url.